# Close pdf-file or exe-application from Python

Tags: python, pyqt

1. My application is opening a pdf-file with os.startfile on user's request (push button). Is there any way to close this pdf when user pushes the button another time? If this is not done, I get the error:

   WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'default_report.pdf'

   **Edit:** Within Python I get: `QPainter::begin(): Returned false` (WindowsError comes from executable). Can I catch this err somehow with `try`? At least to ask user to close the pdf manually...
2. Another related question. My application is compiled as an executable and is called from another, VB6, application (also on push button). Is there any way to detect that executable is already running (exe-file always has the same location) from Python and kill it in this case prior to starting it again? Problem is similar, I get the error if I run the executable second time because they start to conflict (they use common db). From VB6 it doesn't work somehow, I don't know details...

   **Edit**: solved with `psutil` (see my comment to the answer by jheyse)

p.s. I use Python 3.2, PyQt 4 and cx_freeze for exe production if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.I don't think it's directy possible because as the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.startfile) say "startfile() returns as soon as the associated application is launched. There is no option to wait for the application to close, and no way to retrieve the application’s exit status."

2.To kill a process by name from python you can use the [psutil module](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/). Something like this (the following code will kill windows calculator if it is open):

```
for p in psutil.process_iter():
    if p.name == 'calc.exe':
        p.kill()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. 1. I also saw these docs... 2. this way I may try to kill pdf as well, right? Killing myproject.exe from myproject.exe would probably kill itself ;) and that is what I basically need: if one myproject.exe is already running, kill it. Maybe there is a way to check the time when it was started and kill earlier one?

Comment: You can kill myproject.exe from VB6 before calling it again. There are some ways to do it: you could call taskkill from an invisible shell or use dlls (windows API) like [here](http://www.andreavb.com/tip020021.html). Also I think the new versions of Adobe Reader open pdf documents in different processes, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Solved from Python: I detect all `'calc.exe'` processes and `kill()` one with smaller `create_time`. Just works! Thanks again! Problem 1. is not solved but i'll mark the question as solved this evening if nothing comes for that part... p.s. I can't even rely that pdf will be open with Adobe :(

Comment: Excelent solution! The use of the smaller `create_time` was a smart move. Thanks!